# Is it safe to expose the code verifier in the OIDC flow to the frontend code?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect

I'm currently implementing auth via OIDC. My frontend SPA is hosted on a different domain than the backend. When starting the login flow, I need to somehow store the generated code verifier to verify that the login completion request actually comes from the user who started the flow (at least thats how I understood the whole thing). I currently set the code verifier in a signed cookie. That way, I can just read and validate it in my backend. But since my frontend lives on a different domain than my backend, the cookie needs to be SameSite="none" which will become blocked by chrome soon and is already blocked by other browsers.

I thought about encrypting and then passing the code verifier to the frontend SPA which then could save it to local storage, then do the redirect, then when redirected from the issuer to the SPA again, I would read it from local storage and send it along with the request. My backend would decrypt and use it to complete the flow, then return the tokens.

Is this safe to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take control of cookies, separate the backend into 2 parts:

- Backend for Frontend for the SPA
- APIs called by the SPA

The preferred security and protections against XSS are described in [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-the-threat-of-malicious-jav). This results in avoiding returning tokens to the browser.

**URL DESIGN**

The BFF commonly runs in the web domain. Another option, if you own the whole domain, is to host a utility API in a subdomain like this.

- SPA origin: https://www.product.com
- BFF: https://api.product.com/bff
- APIs: https://api.company.com

The SPA makes API requests by routing via the BFF domain. The web entry point to APIs can be an API gateway such as NGINX.

**COOKIES**

The BFF is always in the Same Site as the SPA, though it can be a different origin. The BFF always issues `HTTP Only SameSite=strict` cookies which the browser will not drop.

During login flows, the BFF issues a temporary cookie containing `state` and `code_verifier` values. After login the SPA issues cookies to the browser used for API requests.

**EXAMPLE**

My [example SPA](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final) uses one possible BFF implementation though there are many others in online articles.